# Assistance to portray the tree or box-pointer strucure

Tags: emacs, scheme, racket, sicp

I am working on [Exercise 2.24](https://mitpress.mit.edu/sites/default/files/sicp/full-text/book/book-Z-H-15.html#%_sec_2.2.2) of SICP:

> Exercise 2.24.  Suppose we evaluate the expression (list 1 (list 2
>   (list 3 4))). Give the result printed by the interpreter, the
>   corresponding box-and-pointer structure, and the interpretation of
>   this as a tree (as in figure 2.6).

And draw box-and-pointer as

```
 (1 (2 (3 4)))       ((2 (3 4)))
[*]---------------> [*]
 |                   |
 |                   |
 v                   v (2 (3 4))         ((3 4))
 1                  [*]---------------> [*]
                     |                   |
                     |                   |
                     v                   v (3 4)             (4)
                     2                  [*]---------------> [*]---------------> '()
                                         |                   |
                                         |                   |
                                         v                   v
```

and tree

```
(1 (2 (3 4)))
   *
  / \
 /   \  (2 (3 4))
1     *
     / \
    /   \  (3 4)
   2     *
        / \
       /   \
      3     4
```

Are there any solutions which could portray such tree or box-pointer structures?

It might be very helpful in the beginning since it's not that easy to imagine the structures instantly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you are using Racket, you probably want [sdraw](https://docs.racket-lang.org/sdraw/).  You can get this by, for instance, `raco pkg install sdraw`.